# Add extra cost on a second Cart button

Tags: magento

We want in our store store a second Cart button on the product page.

Why? The client sells custom configured chairs so we got a lot a product custom option with extra cost. And the client want to offer the customers 2 options at the end Full Service or Take and Leave.

He want 2 buttons on the product page "Take and Leave" and " Full Service"

When you click the Take and Leave button it must be 15% cheaper. First i was trying to make it with a extra custom option with a radio button 1 option 0% extra the other 15% extra. Only the custom option are not updating the prices form a the other custom option from the chair. So is not possible this way?

So i was thinking it must be possible to at a second button in de code that minus or add 15% extra from the total price after al the customize options.

What do you think whats the best way?

Comment: Why not use Catalog Price Rule? Add a product attribute and use that as the condition to apply the discount.

Comment: Could you explain? Is it this what possible to get 2 buttons 1 full price the other -15%?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Magento Extra Fee Extension](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension) it will allow you to add extra charge in percentage of product total price when product added to cart.

Comment: I have a look to your demo, is it possible to view the total price with the extra fee on the product price page? And also the make a checkbox on the fee so the client can choose?

Comment: With current version of Extra Fee extension we can not show the price including the extra fee on product page. Also we need to customize the code to add checkbox on product page but selected amount will be added in the cart only & not shown on product page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Add Fee and Discount to Order totals](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total). i managed it to work with check box form cart page to add extra fee in totals.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how to add the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

final result must be something like this:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/545/xmi9.png